# Cannot read property 'length' of null in React component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to build a React list component using a json-like format and materialUI components. I am trying to use a recursive function to build the component but it gives an error:

```
transformed.js:23561 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
at getStyles (transformed.js:23561)
at ListItem.render (transformed.js:23890)
at transformed.js:31579
at measureLifeCyclePerf (transformed.js:30859)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._renderValidatedComponentWithoutOwnerOrContext (transformed.js:31578)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._renderValidatedComponent (transformed.js:31605)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount (transformed.js:31145)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (transformed.js:31041)
at Object.mountComponent (transformed.js:3565)
at ReactDOMComponent.mountChildren (transformed.js:35534)
```

Here is the function I am trying to use:

```
listCreator = (listItems) => {
 let listOutput = null
 listOutput = listItems.map((listSubItem, index) =>
   <ListItem
     key = {index}
     primaryText = {listSubItem.primaryText ? listSubItem.primaryText : null}
     primaryTogglesNestedList = {listSubItem.primaryTogglesNestedList ? listSubItem.primaryTogglesNestedList : null}
     className = {listSubItem.className ? listSubItem.classname : null}
     nestedItems = {listSubItem.nestedItem ? this.listCreator(listSubItem.nestedItems) : null}
   />
 )
 console.log(listOutput)
 return(listOutput)
}
```

Here is the component's state:

```
this.state = {
  categoriesListItems:[
    {
      primaryText:"Item0",
      primaryTogglesNestedList:true,
      nestedItems:
      [{
        primaryText:"Item0Content",
        content: "Testing0...",
      }]
    },
    {
      primaryText:"Item1",
      primaryTogglesNestedList:true,
      nestedItems:
      [{
        primaryText:"Item1Content",
        content: "Testing1...",
      }]
    },
    {
      primaryText:"Item2",
      primaryTogglesNestedList:true,
      nestedItems:
      [{
        primaryText:"Item2Content",
        type: ListItem
      }]
    }
  ]
};
```

Here is the render function:

```
render(){
 return(
   <List>
     {this.listCreator(this.state.categoriesListItems)}
   </List>
)}
```

Here are the three objects returned in my log in my map function:

```
{primaryText: "Item0", primaryTogglesNestedList: true, nestedItems:Array(1)}
 nestedItems: Array(1)
  0: {primaryText: "Item0Content", content: "Testing0..."}
  length: 1
  __proto__ : Array(0)
 primaryText: "Item0"
 primaryTogglesNestedList: true
 __proto__: Object

{primaryText: "Item1", primaryTogglesNestedList: true, nestedItems:Array(1)}
 nestedItems: Array(1)
  0: {primaryText: "Item1Content", content: "Testing1..."}
  length: 1
  __proto__ : Array(0)
 primaryText: "Item1"
 primaryTogglesNestedList: true
 __proto__: Object

{primaryText: "Item2", primaryTogglesNestedList: true, nestedItems:Array(1)}
 nestedItems: Array(1)
  0: {primaryText: "Item2Content", content: type: ƒ}
  length: 1
  __proto__ : Array(0)
 primaryText: "Item2"
 primaryTogglesNestedList: true
 __proto__: Object
```

Comment: How about trying with a simpler version of `listCreator`, for example just logging `listItems`??

Comment: Logging `listItems` just returns my `categoriesListItems`, showing that it is successfully being passed.

Comment: Ok, and logging inside the `map` the `listSubItem` and `index`?? works as expected??

Comment: I'm not sure how to log inside a map, it returns an unexpected token syntax error.

Comment: When I log `listOutput`, it returns the correct elements.

Comment: **1)** Just for checking.. are you using React 16? If no, wrap the `ListItem`'s with a `div`. **2)** Any chance the error could be in another place?

Comment: Figured out how to log in a map function, it returns as expected, but it looks like the function only runs once, suggesting an issue inside the second function call of `listCreator`.

Comment: 1) i'm not sure what version of react i'm using, but wrapping the `ListItem`'s in a `div` doesn't fix the error. 2) If I don't run the function, there is no error.

Comment: I think I got it, `listItems` iterates once because it iterates only in `categoriesListItems`, you need to do something like `listItems.categoriesListItems.map((item)=> {console.log(item)})`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, `listItems` does not contain `categoriesListItems`.

Comment: Ok, and when you logged inside the `map` what did you get? **2)** Are you changing `state` after initialization ( `this.state = { ...` )??

Comment: 1) when I logged inside the `map` I got three objects which is what I was expecting. 2) I am not changing state after initialization.

Comment: Can you post those three objects?

Comment: I've posted the objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following function works because I was returning null instead of an empty list in the `nestedItems` property

```
listCreator = (listItems, nested) => {
 let listOutput = null
  listOutput = listItems.map((listSubItem, index) =>
    <ListItem key = {index}
     primaryText = {listSubItem.primaryText ? listSubItem.primaryText : null}
     primaryTogglesNestedList = {listSubItem.primaryTogglesNestedList ? listSubItem.primaryTogglesNestedList : null}
     className = {listSubItem.className ? listSubItem.classname : null}
     nestedItems = {listSubItem.nestedItems ? this.listCreator(listSubItem.nestedItems, true) : []}
   />
 )
 return(listOutput)
}
```